# Slicing a string from inside a formatted string gives 'TypeError: string indices must be integers'

Tags: python, string, format

Shouldn't both these commands do the same thing?

```py
>>> "{0[0:5]}".format("lorem ipsum")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

```py
>>> "{0}".format("lorem ipsum"[0:5])
'lorem'
```

The commands

```py
>>> "{0[0]}".format("lorem ipsum")
'l'
```

and

```py
>>> "{0}".format("lorem ipsum"[0])
'l'
```

evaluate the same. (I know that I can use other methods to do this, I am mainly just curious as to why it dosen't work)

Comment: Questions about why particular features aren't implemented in Python are not really in the scope of a good Stack Overflow question. "Because that's how it's designed to work" is not necessarily a satisfying answer. All we have are opinions, unless one of the Python developers happens by. However, I will note that f-strings do support slicing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `str.format` syntax is handled by the library and supports only a few “expression” syntaxes that are not the same as regular Python syntax.  For example,

```
"{0[foo]}".format(dict(foo=2))  # "2"
```

works without quotes around the dictionary key.  Of course, there are **limitations** from this simplicity, like not being able to refer to a key with a `]` in it, or interpreting a slice, as in your example.

Note that the f-strings mentioned by kendall are handled by the *compiler* and (fittingly) use [(almost) unrestricted expression syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings).  They **need** that power since they lack the obvious alternative of placing those expressions in the argument list to `format`.